# Fatal error: in base_facebook.php on line 1039

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, iframe, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting the following error

> Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

My frame application consists of two pages - `index.php` and `index1.php`. By default when `index.php` loads, it has following link to `index1.php` at the top:

```
<a href="index1.php">index1</a>
```

and also the following code:

```
<?PHP
include("facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config['appId'] =$appId;
$config['secret'] = $appSecret;
$fb = new Facebook($config);
$access_token = $fb->getAccessToken();
$user_profile = $fb->api('/me','GET');
$userid = $fb->getUser();
?>
```

`index1.php` has same code at the top as index.php is has.

When I load application it doesn't give any error and loads perfectly, but when I click on link to `index1.php` it gives

> Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user in base_facebook.php at 1039

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have an active access token.  To get one, the user must authorize your app and log in.  You might try to `var_dump($access_token)` -- I suspect you may find it returns `null` or `false`

You might try something like

```
if(($access_token = $fb->getAccessToken()) && ($userid = $fb->getUser())) {
    $user_profile = $fb->api('/me','GET');
}
```